# É melhor alterar classes nativas do Bootstrap ou criar subclasses e sobrescrever?

Tags: css, bootstrap

No projeto que estou estudando/trabalhando estou fazendo pequenos ajustes nas classes nativas do Bootstrap para atender minhas necessidades.

1: Esta é realmente a melhor prática? Ou é melhor criarmos nossas classes e sobrescrever as do bootstrap? Ou além disso, há alguma outra prática de uso que seja melhor para personalizarmos nossos projetos?

Por exemplo, abaixo criei uma classe para modificar uma navbar nativa do Bootstrap:

```
.navperson {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 2px solid #5bc0de;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}
```

2: No documento .html, primeiro preciso sempre linkar o .css do bootstrap e depois o .css personalizado, certo? Se aplicarmos o .css do bootstrap depois, ele não vai sobrescrever as propriedades do .css personalizado, certo?

3: A ordem de aplicação das classes altera alguma coisa?

Ex:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navperson">
```

Ou:

```
<nav class="navperson navbar-light navbar-expand-md navbar">
```

Comment: Nesse caso, não existe melhor ou pior, cada pessoa faz de uma forma. Isso depende do que prefere.

Comment: Eu sinceramente gosto de sobrescrever a classe nativa, para não ter 10 classes em um elemento, no fim você acaba ficando meio perdido de qual classe ele está respeitando. Suja o HTML. Mas como o Rafael disse, é gosto. Eu prefiro assim.
E sobre  a ordem de classe, não. A ordem é definida no CSS, pela cascata dele, não importa a ordem da classe no HTML que você colocar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olha, eu tava coçando o dedo para mandar a pergunta para a fila de revisão como "principalmente baseada em opiniões". Mas tem uma coisa sobre boas e más práticas que não é opiniosa, é fato.

A Bootstrap, assim como a enorme maioria das bibliotecas de grande uso, evolui com o tempo. Se o seu sistema for largamente utilizado, ele tenderá a evoluir também.

Se você alterar as classes nativas da Bootstrap ou de qualquer outra biblioteca, você estará dando um tiro no próprio c... er, pé. Toda vez que você for atualizar seu sistema, caso tenha saído uma nova versão das bibliotecas que você adulterou, você terá um trilema:

- Descartar todo o trabalho de alterações que você fez, ou;
- Ficar preso a uma versão obsoleta da biblioteca, ou;
- Fazer um merge do que você fez com a nova versão da biblioteca. Em geral só se vê gente fazendo isso quando se usa projeção astral para visitar os níveis mais baixos do inferno.

Se você utilizar subclasses e sobrescrita, você ainda terá esse problema, mas o impacto vai ser ordens de grandeza menor. A depender de como você fizer isso, o impacto pode ser até insignificante. Em geral, quanto maior a sua habilidade e experiência com reuso, melhor.

O ideal mesmo é não tentar reinventar a roda, e reestilizar essas bibliotecas somente se a sua identidade visual realmente depender disso.